# How to sort according to date in array?

Tags: php

I have an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 120
            [project_id] => 143
            [list_id] => 196
            [task_id] => 620
            [message] => New task created byTester by Rohit Garg
            [date] => 2015-10-30 13:10:54
            [user_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 121
            [project_id] => 143
            [list_id] => 0
            [task_id] => 620
            [message] => Task Completed Tester by Rajat Jain 1
            [date] => 2015-10-30 13:10:18
            [user_id] => 49
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 110
            [project_id] => 143
            [list_id] => 196
            [task_id] => 616
            [message] => New task created bysadasd by saurabh
            [date] => 2015-10-30 12:10:46
            [user_id] => 55
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 109
            [project_id] => 143
            [list_id] => 196
            [task_id] => 0
            [message] => New task list created byadsadasd by saurabh
            [date] => 2015-10-30 12:10:30
            [user_id] => 55
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 108
            [project_id] => 143
            [list_id] => 0
            [task_id] => 0
            [message] => New Project created sdad by saurabh
            [date] => 2015-10-30 12:10:21
            [user_id] => 55
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 114
            [project_id] => 143
            [list_id] => 196
            [task_id] => 618
            [message] => New task created bydsf by saurabh
            [date] => 2015-10-30 12:10:20
            [user_id] => 55
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 111
            [project_id] => 143
            [list_id] => 196
            [task_id] => 617
            [message] => New task created byasdasd by saurabh
            [date] => 2015-10-30 12:10:16
            [user_id] => 55
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 107
            [project_id] => 142
            [list_id] => 0
            [task_id] => 0
            [message] => New Project created sdad by Rohit Garg
            [date] => 2015-10-30 11:10:34
            [user_id] => 1
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 106
            [project_id] => 141
            [list_id] => 195
            [task_id] => 615
            [message] => New task created bysdasd by Rohit Garg
            [date] => 2015-10-30 10:10:37
            [user_id] => 1
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 104
            [project_id] => 141
            [list_id] => 195
            [task_id] => 614
            [message] => New task created bysdsad by Rohit Garg
            [date] => 2015-10-30 10:10:34
            [user_id] => 1
        )

    [10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 103
            [project_id] => 141
            [list_id] => 195
            [task_id] => 0
            [message] => New task list created bydasd by Rohit Garg
            [date] => 2015-10-30 10:10:16
            [user_id] => 1
        )

    [11] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 99
            [project_id] => 140
            [list_id] => 194
            [task_id] => 612
            [message] => New task created bysdasd by saurabh
            [date] => 2015-10-30 10:10:59
            [user_id] => 55
        )

    [12] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 96
            [project_id] => 140
            [list_id] => 194
            [task_id] => 0
            [message] => New task list created by3213123213 by saurabh
            [date] => 2015-10-30 10:10:49
            [user_id] => 55
        )

    [13] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 100
            [project_id] => 140
            [list_id] => 194
            [task_id] => 613
            [message] => New task created bydsfsdf by saurabh
            [date] => 2015-10-30 10:10:34
            [user_id] => 55
        )

    [14] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 97
            [project_id] => 140
            [list_id] => 194
            [task_id] => 611
            [message] => New task created bysas by saurabh
            [date] => 2015-10-30 10:10:08
            [user_id] => 55
        )

    [15] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 122
            [project_id] => 145
            [list_id] => 0
            [task_id] => 0
            [message] => New Project created dfsf by saurabh
            [date] => 2015-10-30 14:10:23
            [user_id] => 55
        )

    [16] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 123
            [project_id] => 145
            [list_id] => 199
            [task_id] => 0
            [message] => New task list created bydasd by saurabh
            [date] => 2015-10-30 14:10:23
            [user_id] => 55
        )

    [17] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 124
            [project_id] => 145
            [list_id] => 199
            [task_id] => 621
            [message] => New task created fsdf by saurabh
            [date] => 2015-10-30 14:10:00
            [user_id] => 55
        )

    [18] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 93
            [project_id] => 139
            [list_id] => 193
            [task_id] => 0
            [message] => New task list created bydasdasd by Rohit Garg
            [date] => 2015-10-30 10:10:48
            [user_id] => 1
        )

    [19] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 92
            [project_id] => 139
            [list_id] => 192
            [task_id] => 0
            [message] => New task list created bydasdasd by Rohit Garg
            [date] => 2015-10-30 10:10:35
            [user_id] => 1
        )

    [20] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 91
            [project_id] => 139
            [list_id] => 191
            [task_id] => 0
            [message] => New task list created bydasdasd by Rohit Garg
            [date] => 2015-10-30 10:10:34
            [user_id] => 1
        )

    [21] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 94
            [project_id] => 139
            [list_id] => 193
            [task_id] => 610
            [message] => New task created bydsad by Rohit Garg
            [date] => 2015-10-30 10:10:09
            [user_id] => 1
        )

)
```

I want to sort according to date in desc. any simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) & [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)-

```
usort($your_array, function($a, $b) { 
    return strtotime($b->date) - strtotime($a->date);
});
```